# How to set jslider default pointers programmatically on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jslider, jquery-slider

I am using [jQuery Slider plugin](http://egorkhmelev.github.io/jslider/) script here is my HTML & JQuery code.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="main">
    <input id="slider" type="slider" name="price" value="20;50" />
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery("#slider").slider({
    from: 10,
    to: 100,
    step: 10,
    round: 1,
    skin: 'plastic',
    limits: true,
    onstatechange: function (value) {
        console.log(value)
    },
});
```

Now my question is, I don't want to use range value inside as textbox value like below:

`<input id="slider" type="slider" name="price" value="20;50" />`

Is it possible to load **20;50** value with Jslider script?

My jsFiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/1gpqzaw6/1/](http://goo.gl/TF3NES)

Any idea or suggestion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling the slider with

```
jQuery("#slider").slider({ 
    ...
```

Try to call it like

```
jQuery("#slider").val("30;50").slider({
    ...
```

This way you can remove the `value` attribute from the `<input>` tag and set the value programmatically before initiating the slider.

Answer (score 0):

just use below code on document ready

```
$("#slider").slider("value",val1,val2 );
```

in my case i used reset button and on-click function

```
function sliderreset()
    {
        $("#slider").slider("value",val1,val2);

    }
```